# LNK2022 between C++/CLI .obj and C# .netmodule with partial class

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, c++-cli, cil

While toying with mixed-language assemblies (e.g. [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/junfeng/2006/05/20/sample-mixing-unmanaged-c-ccli-and-c-code/) or [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MixingLanguagesInASingleAssemblyInVisualStudioSeamlesslyWithILMergeAndMSBuild.aspx)) I came across a couple of bizarre link errors. I am not looking for "don't do that" advice or alternatives, but rather I'd like to understand what these errors are supposed to mean, since neither makes much sense at face value.

C# code:

```
// csppStub.cs
public static partial class To
{
    static partial void Do();
    extern public static bool Done();
}
```

C++ code:

```
// cspp.cpp
public ref class To abstract sealed
{
    // lnk2022 metadata operation failed (801311D6):
    // Differing number of methods in duplicated types (To): (0x02000002).
    static void Do() { }

    // lnk2022 metadata operation failed (801311D8):
    // Differing number of parameters in duplicated method (types: To; methods: Done): (0x06000001).
    public: static bool Done() { return true; }
};
```

VS 2015 project file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="14.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup Label="ProjectConfigurations">
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|Win32">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <ProjectName>cspp</ProjectName>
    <ProjectGuid>{A6FF913B-C27A-4CBC-A847-B15CFA7AE80F}</ProjectGuid>
    <WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>8.1</WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" />
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>DynamicLibrary</ConfigurationType>
    <PlatformToolset>v140</PlatformToolset>
    <CLRSupport>true</CLRSupport>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.props" />
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionSettings">
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'" Label="PropertySheets">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <_ProjectFileVersion>14.0.25123.0</_ProjectFileVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <Link>
      <AdditionalDependencies>$(OutDir)\csppStub.netmodule;%(AdditionalDependencies)</AdditionalDependencies>
      <SubSystem>Windows</SubSystem>
      <LinkTimeCodeGeneration>UseLinkTimeCodeGeneration</LinkTimeCodeGeneration>
    </Link>
    <ClCompile>
      <CompileAsManaged>true</CompileAsManaged>
    </ClCompile>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClCompile Include="cspp.cpp">
      <CompileAsManaged Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">true</CompileAsManaged>
      <ExceptionHandling Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">Async</ExceptionHandling>
    </ClCompile>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <CustomBuild Include="csppStub.cs">
      <Command Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">csc /target:module /out:$(OutDir)\csppStub.netmodule csppStub.cs</Command>
      <LinkObjects Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">false</LinkObjects>
      <Outputs Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">$(OutDir)\csppStub.netmodule</Outputs>
    </CustomBuild>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.targets" />
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionTargets">
  </ImportGroup>
</Project>
```

Build output:

```
Error LNK2022 metadata operation failed (801311D8): Differing number of parameters in duplicated method (types: To; methods: Done): (0x06000001).

Error LNK2022 metadata operation failed (801311D6): Differing number of methods in duplicated types (To): (0x02000002).
```

Comment: Is your C++ class partial?

Comment: @FrancescoB. The C++ code is the ["*full definition*"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cppcx/partial-classes-c-cx#number-and-ordering) of the class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The linker is pretty confounded by what you are trying to do, so its diagnostic is not stellar.  A common issue in C++/CLI code is that it may encounter the same ref class declaration in multiple object files. Caused by the #include directive.  Not something that ever happens in C#, the `partial` keyword is resolved at compile-time.

The linker has to do something about it, it needs to filter down these duplicates to a single definition that it can emit in the metadata. It performs a test to ensure that the class definition are exactly the same. LNK2022 when they are not.  Common causes for that is a macro or different compile options.

But in this case the duplicates came from the C# and the C++/CLI declarations.  Abandon all hope, that will never be a match.  The `extern` keyword does not do what you think it does, it is a directive for the jitter and tells it that it needs to find the function elsewhere.  Not a lot of other places it knows about, nor is it extensible, limited to functions that the CLR implements, [DllImport] declarations and COM interop.

There is no mechanism at all in metadata that resembles `partial`.  You'll have to consider getting ahead with the normal boring way you'd do this in .NET, inheritance and polymorphism.  The C++/CLI class can use the C# class as its base and the C# class can be `abstract`.

Comment: `the partial keyword is resolved at compile-time ... there is no mechanism at all in metadata that resembles partial` Thank you, this pretty much settles it.